# Latest Avogadro build- finding it impossible to install on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, compiling, cmake

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, trying to install the latest version of Avogadro (because the version in Software Center is showing issues) and when I get to `make`, it prints all these errors:

```
[ 98%] Linking CXX shared module ../../../lib/animationextension.so
[ 98%] Linking CXX shared module ../../../lib/povrayextension.so
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen/Core:102:0,
                 from /home/jake/src/avogadro/libavogadro/src/extensions/vrmldialog.h:33,
                 from /home/jake/src/avogadro/libavogadro/src/extensions/vrmldialog.cpp:25:
/usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h: In function ‘Integer Eigen::ei_alignmentOffset(const Scalar*, Integer)’:
/usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:232:51: warning: typedef ‘Packet’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
   typedef typename ei_packet_traits<Scalar>::type Packet;
                                                   ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen/Core:102:0,
                 from /home/jake/build/avogadro/libavogadro/src/extensions/../../../../../src/avogadro/libavogadro/src/extensions/vrmldialog.h:33,
                 from /home/jake/build/avogadro/libavogadro/src/extensions/../../../../../src/avogadro/libavogadro/src/extensions/vrmlextension.h:28,
                 from /home/jake/build/avogadro/libavogadro/src/extensions/moc_vrmlextension.cxx:9:
/usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h: In function ‘Integer Eigen::ei_alignmentOffset(const Scalar*, Integer)’:
/usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:232:51: warning: typedef ‘Packet’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
   typedef typename ei_packet_traits<Scalar>::type Packet;
                                                   ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen/Core:102:0,
                 from /home/jake/build/avogadro/libavogadro/src/extensions/../../../../../src/avogadro/libavogadro/src/extensions/vrmldialog.h:33,
                 from /home/jake/build/avogadro/libavogadro/src/extensions/moc_vrmldialog.cxx:9:
/usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h: In function ‘Integer Eigen::ei_alignmentOffset(const Scalar*, Integer)’:
/usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:232:51: warning: typedef ‘Packet’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
   typedef typename ei_packet_traits<Scalar>::type Packet;
                                                   ^
[ 98%] Built target povrayextension
[ 98%] Built target animationextension
[ 98%] Linking CXX shared module ../../../lib/supercellextension.so
[ 98%] Built target supercellextension
[ 98%] Linking CXX shared module ../../../lib/vrmlextension.so
[ 98%] Built target vrmlextension
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm new to Linux.

What should I do?

Comment: Could you share where you downloaded the source from please?

Comment: @Zanna I have followed these directions, here- [link]http://avogadro.cc/wiki/Compiling_on_Linux_and_Mac_OS_X

Comment: As the link you provided mentions: "be aware that Avogadro may fail to build or work properly at any given time when built using the instructions below"!

Comment: Avogadro 1.1.1 is in Software Center in Ubuntu 16.04. Are you trying to install avogadro-1.2.0 or avogadro-2.0?

Comment: Despite `cmake` exiting successfully (after dealing with dependencies), I was unable to compile Avogadro. This [bug report referring to an older version](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=803657) shows the same linking error as I could not get past "Undefined reference to OpenBabel". I advise you to [report a bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/avogadro/bugs/) or request help on the Avogadro site. Meanwhile, if you need help getting the repository version working, perhaps we can help you with that. Ask a new question with specific information about the errors you are getting.

Comment: I too would like to know how to install the latest version of avogardo. I have tried the version 1.2 from launchpad (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/arm64/avogadro/1.2.0-1), but get "unsatisfiable dependency" for libavogadro1.2 I have tried installing from source code, and found the process even more infuriating.  I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I could post specific errors but I feel this type of question is prone to being ruled off topic.